# How can use string as a function method in python?

Tags: python, function, methods, eval

Hi I am using python and have a dataframe (df) as below:

```
        c      param_values
0   abs_energy  NaN
1   absolute_sum_of_changes NaN
2   agg_autocorrelation [{'f_agg': 'median', 'maxlag': 40}, {'f_agg': ...
3   agg_linear_trend    [{'f_agg': 'max', 'chunk_len': 5, 'attr': 'int...
4   approximate_entropy [{'m': 2, 'r': 0.3}, {'m': 2, 'r': 0.1}, {'m':...
```

I am iterating the above dataframe as below:

I have an import `from tsfresh.feature_extraction import feature_calculators as fc`

```
for i,v in df[1:].iterrows():
    dispatcher={v["calculators"]:eval(str(fc.v["calculators"]))}
    t = eval(v["calculators"],dispatcher)
    print(t)
```

But I get the following error

```
AttributeError: module 'tsfresh.feature_extraction.feature_calculators' has no attribute 'v'
```

I want to evaluate `fc.abs_energy,fc.absolute_sum_of_changes,fc.agg_autocorrelation('median','40')` etc.
How can I find this by iterating the above dataframe. I have tried using eval as shown above but in vain. Please suggest some method. If I have under emphasised/ over emphasised something please let me know in the comments. Thank you

Comment: The error is caused by `fc.v["calculators"])` - `feature_calculators` doesn't have an attribute named `v`. Since you're not prefixing your other references to `v` - did you intend to have that there? You can look up attributes from a string with `getattr` as well, so `fn = getattr(<module>, v['calculators'])` should give you a reference the function itself that you can call without using `eval`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to try importing like this:

`from tsfresh.feature_extraction.feature_calculators import abs_energy,absolute_sum_of_changes,agg_autocorrelation`

And then use this in eval like this:

`eval(str(v["calculators"]))`

## Solution 2

Alternatively, you can change your data in your DataFrame to be like `fc.abs_energy` instead of `abs_energy` and import your module without change:

`from tsfresh.feature_extraction import feature_calculators as fc`

## Caution

Do not forget to concatenate `()` to your string to call the desired function.
For example you have to call `abs_energy` function like this:

`eval('abs_energy()')`